# Can i add watchpoint breakpoint on the UISrollView's contentSize with XCode?

Tags: xcode, uiscrollview, breakpoints

In my code , the contentSize will be incorrect sometimes, can i add a watchpoint on the contentSize so i can know who is changing the contentSize

Answer (score 0):

OK , seems can't add a watch point to watching contentsize ,but the observe will do the same thing as the watchpoint .

```
[self.topScrollView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld  context:nil];
```